# Is it possible to create documentation comments on the right instead on top?

Tags: java, documentation, comments

Documentation can sometimes reduce the readability of code.

Instead of

```
/**
 * The X axis.
 */
int x;

/**
 * The Y axis.
 */
int y;

/**
 * The Z axis.
 */
int z;
```

I'd rather prefer to have

```
int x; /** The X axis */
int y; /** The Y axis */
int z; /** The Z axis */
```

Is there a way in Java to have the comments on the right of e. g. a variable declaration? I've seen it work in C by using the "<" character, but haven't seen it in Java yet. Java is already in Version 8 and I'm wondering why it still isn't possible. Or is it?

Comment: you can use `// my comments` and `/* my comments */`

Comment: @ankur-singhal: These aren't relevant for documentation.

Comment: For documentation comments, we should avoid `//comment`. You can follow http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html as well.

Comment: to answer the question: The javadoc-comment has always to be located BEFORE the code it documents. So no, you cannot write the comment on the right. You could write it to the left: `/** The X axis */ int x;`

Answer (score 1):

[Doc Comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html) work only once. They could be anywhere in the code and many times but only first one is extracted by Javadoc tool. The rest is simple ignored.

Comment: Right. The answer is NO. It's a convention and is easier for the compiler